# confidence interval and sampling distribution for the mean

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error

Ok, I'm having trouble with standard error, sampling distributions and confidence intervals.

The question I am trying to answer is: How many holes do I have to drill in the ground to get good idea of the fracture density (# of fractures / hole).

I simulated a computer model with theoretical fractures.

If I sample the model with 1 hole, the number of intersections could be from zero to about 5... Something in that range. It varies a lot, so I make multiple samples. Let's say I make 100 samples of 1 hole per sample. Then I can easily build a 95% confidence interval for the mean.

Now, I increase to 2 holes per sample and perform 100 samples. In this case, when I build my 95% confidence interval am I using n = 100, or n = 200?

Comment: It depends on your model.

Comment: Hi Glen, how so? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Such as whether there's dependence on observations "in the same hole" or not. If there's no dependence in the model, and no spatial dependence and a constant mean, two holes per sample in 100 holes is exactly as good as 200 holes, one per sample. As those assumptions change, so does the relative value of several samples per hole.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks, that makes sense. I can confirm that the fractures are simulated randomly (as are the hole locations). There is no spatial dependence and there is no dependence on observations in the same hole.

Comment: @Glen_b So, what I am struggling with is this: In real life, you can only drill a few holes in such an area. Therefore, the uncertainty as to what you will encounter is quite large. And confidence intervals with such few samples change so much each time I run the program (different random number seed each time). So that's why I was using such large sample sizes, to get smooth confidence intervals. But we will never have that many samples in real life. So perhaps the answer to my question above is: "Too many". Not sure if that helps, but any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The direct answer to the question, given the assumptions you mention in comments, is "n=200". If the distribution of fractures per hole is assumed the same for every hole and the observations in a hole were independent, it doesn't matter how many observations per hole you take. But I don't think those assumptions are likely to be realistic for actual samples. With dependence, you'd incorporate it in your model and (generally) still call n=200 (though in effect the 'effective n' by comparison with independent observations would be smaller). ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd)... I think a proper answer to this would have to get down to discussing suitable models. I am not sure I'm the best person to suggest models in this application